# Angular translate provider - Is there a way to replace general variables?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angular-translate

In my app, many of my translation string need to include the user name in them.
For example: `Hello {{user_name}}!`
(User name has to be part of the translation string since the position of the name in the string depends on the language))

The way to set attributes is `{{"TRANSLATE_ID" | translate:{user_name:myUserName}}}`

Since `{{user_name}}` appears in more than 100 translation strings, I don't want to send the `user_name` parameter so many times. I'd like to have a way to set this parameter only one.

I can't replace the `{{user_name}}` string in the config because the user_name is set asynchronously (fetched from the server) and isn't available when `translateProvider` sets the strings.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

AngularTranslate allows you to translate tags from the html itself or inside the controller through a promise. I believe the elegant way to do what you want is to create a method/function in your controller that handles the translation in the way you want and then call this method/function in your html passing the username as a parameter.

Address the username in your JSON translation files as "USERNAME" for instance, such as "Hello, USERNAME!", do the translation in a method created in your controller using AngularTranslate and then do a string replacement changing the word USERNAME for the method parameter (the real username) and use this string as the method's return value, which will be called in your html.

Hope this helps.